# Paste values of 2 list of different length together

Tags: python

I would like to 'paste' the values of 2 lists of different lenght together

For example I have those lists

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

So the desired output would be :

`['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']`

I found a way to achieve it by doing :

```
li = []
for yy in y : 
  li += list(map(lambda xx : yy + str(xx), x))
```

But I'm not sure if it's the Python way to do it or even if it's good at all.

Is there a better option ?
Thank you

Comment: `[f"{y_item}{x_item}" for y_item in y for x_item in x]` returns your desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use nested `for` loops

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [f'{c}{i}' for c in y for i in x]    
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

or since this is an iteration problem, throw `itertools` at it

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [f'{c}{i}' for c, i in product(y, x)]
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```